# pandas query with a column consisting of array entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

```
ykp.data
Out[182]: 
    state  action  reward  
0    [41]       5      59  
1     [5]      52      48  
2    [46]      35      59  
3    [42]      16      12  
4    [43]      37      48   
5    [36]       5      59   
6    [49]      52      48 
7    [39]      11      23
```

I would like to find the row that matches [42] in the state entry so I ran

```
ykp.data.query('state == [42]')
```

but I get

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [state, action, reward]
Index: []
```

when I should be seeing `[42], 16, 12`.

Can someone please tell me how I can workaround this? I need my state-values to be stored as arrays.

Comment: Can you store them as tuples?

Comment: Usually better to work with tuples, but you can use `apply`: `df.loc[df.state.apply(lambda x: x==[42])]`

Answer (score 4):

Best to avoid `pd.Series.apply` here. Instead, you can use `itertools.chain` to construct a regular NumPy array. Then compare the array to an integer to form a Boolean array for indexing:

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100000, 1)), columns=['state'])
df = df.assign(state=df.state.apply(lambda x: [x]), axis=1)

def wen(df):
    df.state=df.state.astype(str)
    return df.query("state == '[42]'")

%timeit df[np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(df['state'].values))) == 42]  # 14.2 ms
%timeit df[df.state.apply(tuple) == (42,)]                                 # 41.9 ms
%timeit df.loc[df.state.apply(lambda x: x==[42])]                          # 33.9 ms
%timeit wen(df)                                                            # 19.9 ms
```

Better still, don't use lists in your dataframe. Just use regular `int` series. This will be memory and performance efficient.

Comment: Nice ! :) if all lists have `len` 1, can do `.str.get(0)` and make em all `int`s. Good catch with `np.array`+`chain`

Comment: @RafaelC, Agreed! Though `str.get(0)` seems to be pretty slow.

Comment: Interesting ! never measures `.str.get`. Is there a better way? maybe `transform` with `k[0]` as lambda, or is there a vectorized solution

Comment: @RafaelC, No vectorised solution is possible since you are starting with a bunch of pointers. Getting a bunch of pointers into a contiguous array is a non-vectorised operation.

Comment: Would you like check timing of mine

Comment: @Wen, Sure, added :)

Comment: @jpp seems no bad , ah :-) vote for your additional effort :-)

Comment: @RafaelC yep convert to string is bad at timing for sure

Comment: Guess the bottom line is: don't use columns of lists haha ;p

Answer (score 2):

You can adding `astype(str)`

```
df.state=df.state.astype(str)
df.query("state == '[42]'")
Out[290]: 
  state  action  reward
3  [42]      16      12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print df[df.state.apply(tuple) == (42,)]
  state  action  reward
3  [42]  16      12
```

Another solution (from the @user3483203 comment below):

```
df.loc[df.state.apply(lambda x: x==[42])]
```

But the original is 14% faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100000, 1)), columns=['state'])
df = df.assign(state=df.state.apply(lambda x: [x]), axis=1)

%timeit df[df.state.apply(tuple) == (42,)]
10 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ms per loop

%timeit df.loc[df.state.apply(lambda x: x==[42])]
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: If you're using `apply` anyways, why not just `df.loc[df.state.apply(lambda x: x==[42])]`

Comment: @user3483203 thank you, I tested it and updated the answer.