# query dataframe column on array values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
traj0
Out[52]: 
         state         action  reward
0   [1.0, 4.0, 6.0]     3.0     4.0
1   [4.0, 6.0, 11.0]    4.0     5.0
2   [6.0, 7.0, 3.0]     3.0    22.0
3   [3.0, 3.0, 2.0]     1.0    10.0
4   [2.0, 9.0, 5.0]     2.0     2.0
```

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe looking like this where the state column has as its entries, 3-element numpy arrays.

How can I query for the row that has state as `np.array([3.0,3.0,2.0])` here?

I know `traj0.query("state == '[3.0,3.0,2.0]'")` works, I know. But I don't want to hardcode the array value in my query.

I'm looking for something like

```
x = np.array([3.0,3.0,2.0])
traj0.query('state ==' + x)
```

=============

It's not a duplicate question because my previous question [pandas query with a column consisting of array entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488681/pandas-query-with-a-column-consisting-of-array-entries/51489007#51489007) was only for the case where there was only one value in each array. Here I'm looking for if the arrays have multiple values.

Comment: why not just store them in separate columns to begin with: `state_1`, `state_2`, `state_3`?

Comment: How we define state is a vector of several values. I have to for this project.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.array([1.0, 4.0, 6.0]), 3.0, 4.0],
              [np.array([4.0, 6.0, 11.0]), 4.0, 5.0],
              [np.array([6.0, 7.0, 3.0]), 3.0, 22.0],
              [np.array([3.0, 3.0, 2.0]), 1.0, 10.0],
              [np.array([2.0, 9.0, 5.0]), 2.0, 2.0]
             ], columns=['state','action','reward'])

x = str(np.array([3.0, 3.0, 2.0]))
df[df.state.astype(str) == x]

// to use pd.query
df['state_str'] = df.state.astype(str)
df.query("state_str == '{}'".format(x))
```

Output

```
    state           action  reward
3   [3.0, 3.0, 2.0] 1.0     10.0
```

Comment: Note string conversion is expensive. It should not be required, in general, for NumPy arrays.

Comment: @jpp I agree, and I really like your solution. However, if @Glassjawed is looking to use `pd.query` this is one way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and a lambda function using [`numpy.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
x = [1., 4., 6.]
traj0.loc[df.state.apply(lambda a: np.array_equal(a, x))]
```

Basically this checks each element of the `state` column for equivalence to `x` and returns only those rows where the column matches.

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'state': [[1., 4., 6.], [4., 5., 6.]],
                        'value': [5, 6]})
print(df.loc[df.state.apply(lambda a: np.array_equal(a, x))])

             state  value
0  [1.0, 4.0, 6.0]      5
```

Comment: Note this is equivalent to a `for` loop. It doesn't take advantage of NumPy vectorised operations.

Answer (score 0):

Best *not* to use `pd.DataFrame.query` here. You can perform a vectorised comparison and then use Boolean indexing:

```
x = [3, 3, 2]
mask = (np.array(df['state'].values.tolist()) == x).all(1)

res = df[mask]

print(res)

             state  action  reward
3  [3.0, 3.0, 2.0]     1.0    10.0
```

In general, you shouldn't store lists or arrays within a Pandas series. This is inefficient and removes the possibility of direct vectorised operations. Here, we've had to convert to a NumPy array explicitly for a simple comparison.

Comment: I don't want the state value to be hardcoded. So if I said x=[3,3,2]...how can I use this?